# It is not displaying all the songs in the Album

Tags: java

```
        package com.company;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class JukeBox {
            public String Singer_Name;
            ArrayList<Album>Albums;

            public JukeBox(String singer_Name) {
                Singer_Name = singer_Name;
                this.Albums=new ArrayList<Album>();
            }

            public boolean CreatAlbum(String Album_Name){
                if(findAlbum(Album_Name)==null){
                    this.Albums.add(new Album(Album_Name));
                    return  true;
                }
                return false;
            }


            public boolean addSongs(String Album_Name,String Singer_Name,float Song_Duration,String released_Day){
                Album Alb = findAlbum(Album_Name);
                if(Alb!=null){
                    Alb.Creeat(Singer_Name,Song_Duration,released_Day);
                    return true;
                }
                return  false;
            }
            public void AlbumNames(){
                for(Album Alb:this.Albums){
                    System.out.println(Alb.getAlbum_Name());
                }
            }



            private Album findAlbum(String Album_Name){
                for(int i=0;i<this.Albums.size();i++){
                    Album Alb=this.Albums.get(i);
                    if(Alb.getAlbum_Name().equals(Album_Name))
                        return Alb;
                }
                return null;
            }





         public boolean AlbumSOngs(String Album_Name){
         Album Alb = findAlbum(Album_Name);

         if(Alb!=null){
             System.out.println("Songs in Album "+Alb.getAlbum_Name());
             ArrayList<Songs>SongList= Alb.getSongs();
             for(int i=0;i<SongList.size();i++){
                 System.out.println(SongList.get(i).Song_Name);
                 return true;
             }

         }
         return false;
         }

        }
    //Album Class

    package com.company;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Album {

        public String Album_Name;

        ArrayList<Songs>songs;

        public Album(String album_Name) {
            Album_Name = album_Name;
            this.songs=new ArrayList<Songs>();
        }

        public boolean Creeat(String Song_Name,float Song_duration,String releasedDay ){
            if(findSong(Song_Name)==null){
                this.songs.add(new Songs(Song_Name,Song_duration,releasedDay));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private Songs findSong(String Song_Name){
            for (int i = 0; i < this.songs.size(); i++) {
                Songs song = this.songs.get(i);
                if (song.getSong_Name().equals(Song_Name)) {
                    return song;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        public String getAlbum_Name() {
            return Album_Name;
        }

        public ArrayList<Songs> getSongs() {
            return songs;
        }

    }
//Song Class
package com.company;

public class Songs {
    public String Song_Name;
    public float Song_duration;
    public String Song_releasedDay;

    public Songs(String song_Name, float song_duration, String song_releasedDay) {
        Song_Name = song_Name;
        Song_duration = song_duration;
        Song_releasedDay = song_releasedDay;
    }

    public String getSong_Name() {
        return Song_Name;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't displaying all the songs name in the album however when i try to display all albums name it works perfectly but whenever i try to print the songs in any album it displays only the first song name in the album and ignore the reset the jukebox class has the album in array List the Album Class has the Songs in an array list ...

Comment: inside your `for` loop, you call `return true` which will immediately end execution of the function and cause it return `true`

Comment: Remove this.songs=new ArrayList<Songs>();

Comment: why  removing it it should get List of songs no ?

Comment: It works thanks a lot man ! <3

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase. So they start with lowercase, and they have no underscores.

Comment: Furthermore, the fields of your `Song` class do not have to start with "Song", as they already belong to `Song`. Names like `name` and `duration` would suffice.

Comment: advice earned thanks MC